# Mule VM Endpoint

Tags: xml, mule, endpoint

Mule 3.3.1 CE

I'm probably going to kick myself, but what's going on with the following?

I have a private flow that takes in an XML payload and extracts a value among other things.  This cut-down example works.

```
<flow name="MyFlow">
    <set-session-variable variableName="xyzMethod" value="#[xpath:local-name(/S:Envelope/S:Body/*[1])]"/>
</flow>
```

I want to put a VM inbound endpoint on this to solve some reuse issues.  However, when I do, I get an exception on that xpath invocation.  This exhibits the problem.

```
<flow name="MyFlow">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" path="execute.xyz"/>
    <set-session-variable variableName="dnbMethod" value="#[xpath:local-name(/S:Envelope/S:Body/*[1])]"/>
</flow>
```

I'm not seeing something obvious.  What does the insertion of the VM endpoint do that is causing this?

```
Message               : There are two transformers that are an exact match for input: "class java.lang.String", output: "interface org.dom4j.Document". Transformers are: "XmlToDom4jDocument(class org.mule.module.xml.transformer.XmlToDomDocument)" and "XmlToDom4jDocument(class org.mule.module.xml.transformer.XmlToDomDocument)"
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-255
```

**EDIT based upon discussion below**

Based upon the discussion of trying MEL syntax, here are some results.

The input is (except for security info):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sch="http://applications.dnb.com/webservice/schema/">
<soapenv:Header>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
  <sch:AdvancedCompanySearchRequest>
  </sch:AdvancedCompanySearchRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The following is the exact code that executes successfully.  I see AdvancedCompanySearchRequest in the console.

```
<flow name="ExecuteDandB" doc:name="ExecuteDandB">
<!--    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" path="execute.dnb" doc:name="DnB"/>-->

    <set-session-variable variableName="dnbMethod" value="#[xpath:local-name(/S:Envelope/S:Body/*[1])]"/>
<!--    <set-session-variable variableName="dnbMethod" value="#[xpath('/S:Envelope/S:Body/*[1]').name]"/>-->
    <logger level="INFO" message="#[sessionVars['dnbMethod']]"/>        
</flow>
```

The following is the exact code that fails to execute.  I see the exception about two transformers described above.

```
    <flow name="ExecuteDandB" doc:name="ExecuteDandB">
<!--    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" path="execute.dnb" doc:name="DnB"/>-->

<!--    <set-session-variable variableName="dnbMethod" value="#[xpath:local-name(/S:Envelope/S:Body/*[1])]"/>-->
    <set-session-variable variableName="dnbMethod" value="#[xpath('/S:Envelope/S:Body/*[1]').name]"/>
    <logger level="INFO" message="#[sessionVars['dnbMethod']]"/>        
</flow>
```

Comment: Wow (o_O) Can you try using MEL instead of the old style expression syntax to see if it alleviates the issue. See: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/MEL+Cheat+Sheet#MELCheatSheet-XPathSupport

Comment: I'd be glad to, but I can't seem to figure out what the corresponding syntax is.  Mule's documentation is rather sketchy on examples.  If the old syntax is "#[xpath:local-name(/S:Envelope/S:Body/*[1])]"...i.e., local node name for the first child of Body, what would the MEL equivalent be?  I've tried "#[local-name(xpath('/S:Envelope/S:Body/*[1]'))]" and "#[xpath('/S:Envelope/S:Body/*[1]').local-name]" but neither of those are correct.

Comment: Since you use an expression manager, I think you need to prefix XPath functions with `fn`, ie: `#[xpath('fn:local-name(/S:Envelope/S:Body/*[1])')]`. If this doesn't work, we can get the local name from the Dom4J node with: `#[xpath('/S:Envelope/S:Body/*[1]').name]`

Comment: @David, MEL makes things worse in a sense.  Using the old syntax, I can parse if the flow has no inbound VM endpoint but not if it does.  Using MEL syntax, it fails even without the inbound VM endpoint.  I've edited the question above to show examples.  Btw, I tried both of the xpath syntaxes you suggested; they both gave the same results.

Comment: I don't see any recursion in the config above?

Comment: Whoops, actually deleted my last comment by mistake.  No, you won't see the recursion because I've boiled this down to the minimum flow to produce the problem.  I'm going to try to solve the recursion problem another way, I guess while I beat away at this.

Comment: What's the payload type of the input sent to the VM inbound? String? byte[]? other?

Comment: It's a string payload.

Comment: One of the things that I'm finding hard to understand is that the exceptions say there are two transformers that can translate from String to Document...and then lists the same transformer twice.

Comment: I've seen this happen when several versions of the same Mule JARs is used. Not the case for you?

Comment: I don't believe so.  I have 3.3.1 CE on this machine and the associated Mule Studio.  I'll do some exploring to make sure I haven't inadvertently copied something into the classpath.  It's puzzling that the old syntax works but not the new.  Or, is that something you would expect?

Comment: No, it smells like a bug. Do you mind trying on 3.4.0 CE please?

Answer (score 1):

You'll find the solution here:

http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/no_idea_why_i_am_getting_this_error-csv8r

It's about having two copies of mule-module-xml.jar in your classpath.

Comment: Even if the link contains a complete answer, please , add an explanation. Your answer should stand for itself without reference.